# JSON::ParserError: 767: unexpected token at 'MyText' (Rails & Minitest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting some JSON parser errors when I run the tests on my Rails (5.2) app. This is an example:

> ERROR["test_should_show_photo", Minitest::Result, 5.387737000361085]
> test_should_show_photo#Minitest::Result (5.39s)
> Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActionView::Template::Error: 767: unexpected token at 'MyText'
> app/views/photos/show.html.erb:2:in >`_app_views_photos_show_html_erb___4241643449401419846_70111557791480' test/controllers/photos_controller_test.rb:27:in` block in class:PhotosControllerTest'

The error occurs at the lines when the @photo instance variable is called in the code below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PhotosControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @photo = photos(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get photos_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_photo_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create photo" do
    assert_difference('Photo.count') do
      post photos_url, params: { photo: { image_data: @photo.image_data } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to photo_url(Photo.last)
  end

  test "should show photo" do
    get photo_url(@photo)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_photo_url(@photo)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update photo" do
    patch photo_url(@photo), params: { photo: { image_data: @photo.image_data } }
    assert_redirected_to photo_url(@photo)
  end

  test "should destroy photo" do
    assert_difference('Photo.count', -1) do
      delete photo_url(@photo)
    end

    assert_redirected_to photos_url
  end
end
```

**setup** calls the yaml file below:

```
one:
  image_data: MyText (This must be where the problem is)

two:
  image_data: MyText
```

I assume that the issue here is that **MyText** is not JSON syntax, but I can't figure out how to change it so that the tests pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I figured out how to fix this, and I wanted to return with the solution in case it can help anybody else.*

The issue was indeed that the default scaffold generate .yml file was not valid json.

The solution I came up with was to copy and paste a record from the database that I had successfully saved previously. I opened up the Rails Console and looked up a valid record for photo and wrapped it in single quotes:

```
one:

image_data: '{"id":"164214a2b7a969102f90edadccaae62b.jpg","storage":"store","metadata":{"filename":"changes.jpg","size":24434,"mime_type":"image/jpeg"}}'
```

After that, all the failing tests passed.